# How to read top users page of a tag?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, top-users

How to interpret following image:

[image]

What does values in red box means? and what does values in blue box means? As there are no headers its hard to read. I think there should be headers so that users can understand it better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Left number (red box) = Score = (# of upvotes - # of downvotes) for answers in that tag
Right number (blue box) = Number of answers in that tag

On any Stack Exchange site, hovering your mouse over something you don't understand will often lead to helpful information.

Comment: means first one has got 766 up votes or total score of voting is 766?

Comment: @Harry 766 is the number of upvotes minus the number of downvotes