# Top Users in a tag criteria

Tags: bug, top-users

I noticed something odd today with the [biml](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/biml/topusers) tag.

[image]

4 questions in the past 30 days, 4 of which have been answered (by me). Prior to posting this, each of my answers were at 0 upvotes (all hail the unsung hero).

I see that "Only non community-wiki questions and answers are included in these totals (updated daily)" but none of the questions were cw.

### Question the first

Is the top users logic then that people will only be listed if they have had upvotes, regardless of answer acceptance?

### Question the second

If that logic, answer score > 0, is true, does that truly reflect top tag users?

### Research

Searching on top users netted the related questions.

- [How to read top users page of a tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85119/how-to-read-top-users-page-of-a-tag)
- [When is the top user generated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68890/when-is-the-top-user-generated)
- [Accepted answers count on top users page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25104/accepted-answers-count-on-top-users-page)
- ["Top Users" page should also list the people with the most accepted answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71572/top-users-page-should-also-list-the-people-with-the-most-accepted-answers)
- [Adjust ranking of top users for tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196511/adjust-ranking-of-top-users-for-tags)

Comment: For Q1, yes that's tag scores i.e. number of net votes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Answer the first

The users are picked in the tag page according to total of the scores they have made, a simple hover over the numbers will show a tooltip saying that.

### Answer the second

Yes, I do not know why SE people chose this criteria (score instead of acceptance), but IMO scores will definitely reflect the opinion of larger number of people, while acceptance will only reflects the opinion of the askers, a question can only have one asker, but millions of up/down voters. I also do not see how can they (SE people) come up with a criteria the combines both things, acceptance and score. So the safest and the most accurate would be the score.

Comment: Seems reasonable on the second part

Comment: The Top pages also show the number of asked/answered questions - numbers which don't count in the display order of top users. The accepted answers could be added as well.

Comment: And I don't think you answer the first question. A total of 0 score is still a score. I don't see anywhere in the tooltip to declare a *"positive score"*

Comment: @ypercube you are right, it doesn't specify "positive score", but I guess " **TOP** askers and answerers" implies that, I suppose.

Comment: @ypercube not only positive, it also picks up the top 20, so this should be mentioned as well (top 20 users with positive scores".